# How can I read MifareClassic card with NFC Android?

Tags: android, rfid, nfc, mifare

I am working with NFC Android programming and I want to read Mifare Classic cards.  Does anybody know how to read the sectors off such a card?

My problem is the `transceive()` method. I don't know how to use it to read a sector 
for example to read sector 1.

Authentication method returns true which means that authentication is done. After authentication, sector should be ready for any IO action  but whenever i use readBlock() method or transceive() method, I get exception with  IOException("transceive failed"). 
I can not find any example which uses the Mifare Classic, so i want to know if it is possible to read the Mifare Classic with this API or not.

Kind Regards.

Comment: Two suggestions: add android as tag, and probably structure the question a bit more reader-friendly.

Comment: Take a look at
http://mifareclassicdetectiononandroid.blogspot.com/2011/04/reading-mifare-classic-1k-from-android.html

Answer (score 9):

It is for sure possible to read Mifare Classic with this API - we have applications that do it.

You shouldn't need to use `transceive()` directly if you just want to read the card - just use the `readBlock()` convenience method.

A common pitfall is that authentication is done on the **sector** level, whereas reading is done on a **block** level. On Mifare Classic, a sector is comprised of several blocks. Unfortunately, the number of blocks per sector may vary, even on the same card.

Use `MifareClassic.sectorToBlock(sector)` to retrieve the first starting block of the sector that you authenticated for. Then, you may read all blocks of that sector. The number of blocks in a sector can be retrieved with `MifareClassic.getBlockCountInSector(sector)`.

If it still doesn't work, can you post some code?

Comment: what about writing? does your application also write? whenever I Authenticate my sector 38 with authenticateSectorWithKeyB() I get true but when i call writeBlock() I get exception.